# How many 5 digit numbers are there that doesn't have "13" in them?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

What is the general formula for N digits?
1 and 3 can exist in the number but they can't be next to each other.
For example, **13**598 or 54**13**5 isn't allowed because they have "13" in them but 51431 is allowed because there is no "13" in the number. Am assuming that this can be solved with permutations and combinations but I just can't seem to figure out the general formula for N digits.

Comment: You distinguish $13$ but the rule you mention would appear to exclude $31$ as well.  Regardless, the recursion should be easy.

Comment: @Forester wdym? I want to know how many N digit numbers are there that doesn't have "13" in them.

Comment: @lulu Yeah 31 is excluded, it has to be 1 and then 3, 3 followed by 1 is allowed/

Comment: You specifically say that $51431$ is allowed.  But, it really doesn't matter.  Recursive methods work in all (sensible) cases.

Comment: @lulu yeah it's allowed as in you can count it as not having "13" in it. For example if we took 2 digits instead of 5 digits, then there are 99 numbers that doesn't have "13" in them. Here 31 is allowed because it doesn't have "13" in it.

Comment: @MythreyaHardur Your title says 5 digits and your body says n digits.

Comment: I expect there is a translation issue.  "excluded" means "not allowed".

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_N$ be the number of $N$-digit numbers which does not have $13$ in them.

Let $b_N$ be the number of $N$-digit numbers which ends with $1$ and does not have $13$ in them.

Then for $N \geq 1$ we have:

- $a_{N + 1} = 10 a_N - b_N$

  because one can append any digit from $0$ to $9$ to every $N$-digit number. The only case where a number containing $13$ is created is when the original number ends with $1$ and one appends $3$ to it.
- $b_{N + 1} = a_N$

  because removing the last $1$ gives an $N$-digit number and vice-versa.

---

The rest is simply solving this linear recursion, which is standard.